# Polynomial of Degree $n$ over a field has at most $n$ zeros, counting multiplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proof : We proceed by induction on $n$

If $f$ is constant, clearly $f$ has no zero.

Suppose for all $f$ with degree $n-1$ holds the statement

Let $g$ with degree $n$ and $a$ is a zero of $g$

then $g(x)=(x-a)^kq(x)$ and $q(a)$ is not zero

> From now, my book add some logic , but I don't understand why author add this part to show the statement. Subsequent proof is as follow : If $g$ has no zeros other than $a$, we are done. On the other hand, if $b$ is not equal to $a$ and $b$ is a zero of $f$, then $0=g(b)=(b-a)^kq(b)$, so that $b$ is also a zero of $q(x)$ with multiplicity as it has for $f(x)$.

Since, deg $g$=$k$+deg $q$, deg $q$ = $n-k$

By induction hypothesis, $q$ has at most $n-k$ zeros ,counting multiplicity

Thus $g$ has at most $k+n-k=n$ zeros, considering multiplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given $f(x)\in{\Bbb K}[x]$ and $a\in{\Bbb K}$. Then
$$f(a) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \exists g\in{\Bbb K}[x]: f(x) = g(x) \cdot (x-a).$$
Prove this by using the usual division algorithm.

Iterating this gives
$$f(x) = (x-a_1)^{k_1}\cdots (x-a_m)^{k_m} g(x)$$
where $a_1,\ldots,a_m\in{\Bbb K}$, $k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 1$, and $g(x)$ has no root in ${\Bbb K}$.

Comment: Based on your hint, my curious part shows that $q(x)$ has at least one zeros in given field. If $q(x)$ doesn't have zero in given field, we can't apply induction hypothesis. right??

Comment: For instance, $x^2+1$ has no zero in ${\Bbb R}$. In my last equation, $f=g$.